# Custom fonts not displaying correctly on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts

I'm trying to get a set of Neo Sans Pro fonts working on the iPhone. I have four weights: Light, Regular, Medium, Bold as OTF files (NeoSansPro-Light.otf, -Regular.otf etc). The files are included in the build, and registered in the info.plist.

Calling `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Neo Sans Pro"]` returns an array with 4 entries e.g. "NeoSansPro-Light".

I can retrieve font objects for each of these strings using `UIFont fontWithName:size:`.

However, when I draw text with them, the Light, Regular and Medium versions all draw exactly the same, and look like the Light version. The Bold version draws differently.

According to Font Book, each font file does contain different glyphs.

I'm completely stumped - any clues what I need to do?

[Added]
Some more investigation:

```
 NSArray *fonts = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Neo Sans Pro"];

    for (NSString *fname in fonts) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fname size:12.0];
        NSLog(@"name: %@ font: %@", fname, font);
    }
```

Running this code gives the following log output:

```
 name: NeoSansPro-Light font: <UICFFont: 0x66304a0> font-family: "Neo Sans Pro"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px
 name: NeoSansPro-Regular font: <UICFFont: 0x66304a0> font-family: "Neo Sans Pro"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px
 name: NeoSansPro-Medium font: <UICFFont: 0x66304a0> font-family: "Neo Sans Pro"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px
 name: NeoSansPro-Bold font: <UICFFont: 0xaa06070> font-family: "Neo Sans Pro"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px
```

So the three fonts that display the same really are the same. But there's four font weights and four fonts in the build.

Comment: Also tried as TTF files, but same happened

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this is the same problem as here: [Including multiple fonts of the same family in an iPad application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231391/including-multiple-fonts-of-the-same-family-in-an-ipad-application)

It seems the iOS font architecture gets confused if there are multiple fonts in the same font family, and won't hand back the right font. The solution is to manually edit the font family information (using something like [Font Forge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to different values.

E.g. For the Neo Sans Pro Light font, set the Font family (in the PSNames and TTF Names) to "NSP Light". Do similarly for Neo Sans Pro Regular -> NSP Regular etc.

You can then refer to the font by the original name e.g. "NeoSansPro-Light"

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: A few clarifications: In Font Forge, this is available in the 'Element' menu under 'Font Info.'  Also, it doesn't really matter what you set the Font family to, basically you're just changing it from the original family so that iOS finds it by its unique name, not family/weight.

Answer (score 0):

Font forge looked a bit too much for me so I created a method that reads descriptions of the fonts in the fontsArray of a certain family and returns appropriate font.

```
- (UIFont*) getFontWithFamilyName:(NSString*)familyName bold:(Boolean)bold italic:(Boolean)italic size:(uint)size {
    NSArray *fonts = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for (NSString *fname in fonts) {
       UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fname size:size];
       Boolean isBold = [[font description] rangeOfString:@"bold"].location != NSNotFound;
       Boolean isItalic = [[font description] rangeOfString:@"italic"].location != NSNotFound;
       if (isBold == bold && isItalic == italic) {
          return font;
       }
    }
    //-- font was not found, provide system font bold or normal
    if (bold) {
       return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:size];
    } else {
       return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this with several fonts from the same family installed? The problem I was seeing was the [UIFont fontWithName:] didn't work, so your solution wouldn't either

Comment: Obviously, this works if [UIFont fontWithName:] returns something. If it doesn't for you, I am not sure whether the problem is that you have multiple fonts of the same family. Multiple fonts should return multiple array entries

Comment: I agree that [UIFont fontWithName] *should* return multiple items, but since it *doesn't* there's a bug in the Apple code. Hence work-around above.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Google font named Arvo. It had the following files:

- Arvo-Regular.ttf
- Arvo-Bold.ttf
- Arvo-BoldItalic.ttf
- Arvo-Italic.ttf

These names were added into my app's info.plist but for some reason, my app could only read the bold, bolditalic, and italic fonts. It couldn't read the regular font when i tried to load it. However, after printing out the font names, it came out that Arvo-Regular was recognized as Arvo in my app.