# Custom fonts with multiple variations not working with Alloy and Titanium 3.0.2

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I've followed all of the instructions to get the custom fonts loaded properly into the app. It seems as though that's working properly as I'm able to reference the standard font ("Open Sans", in this case) without issue. The problem I have is that I've loaded multiple variations of "Open Sans", one of them being "Open Sans Light". In Font Book on Mac the font name for all of the variations is "Open Sans". How do I reference the "Light" version properly in Titanium? I've tried:

- "Open Sans - Light"
- "Open Sans Light"
- "OpenSans-Light"
- "OpenSansLight"

.. the ones above which work just use the default "Open Sans" font, and not the "Light" version. Is there a way to get this to work properly?

Here's my TSS code:

```
".revolutionize": {
    top: 404.5,
    left: 72.5,
    font: {fontFamily: "OpenSans-Light", fontSize: "27"},
    color: "#ffffff"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I realized this morning that Titanium is actually using the *Light* version for everything and it's the *Regular* version I'm not able to reference. I've tried setting fontWeight to "Normal" and "Regular" and it still uses the Light version of the font.

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to solve this using the font as it was named initially, but following the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738929/custom-fonts-not-displaying-correctly-on-ios) I was able to use Font Forge to rename the fonts and successfully use both variations in my Titanium iPad app. Hope this helps someone else! I'm not sure if this bug is an iOS issue or a Titanium issue but I will update [the issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-2000) as well.

Answer (score -1):

actually you need to give like this ..delete your built and run with below code

```
font: {fontFamily: "OpenSans",fontWeight:"Light", fontSize: "27"},
```

Comment: and one more thing when you click ont the font it will show you that want to install in mac on top center you would find font family and weight ... you can use that

Comment: "Light" is not a valid option for fontWeight according to the Titanium docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Font-property-fontWeight. I actually tried that myself and I remember it didn't work.