# How to iOS adding custom font with same name but different weight?

Tags: ios

I have a problem of adding custom font with same name but different weight like:

```
[_lblFullName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans 500" size:20]];
[_lblTicket setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans 900" size:12]];
```

I can only make this work by adding only one font weight but i have to rename it `Museo Sans` and only import one font to bundle and delete the other font. like:

```
[_lblFullName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:20]];
[_lblTicket setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:12]];
```

But it only allows me one font weight, I need to have to import this two font weight.
Please help.

Comment: Check this, this will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231391/including-multiple-fonts-of-the-same-family-in-an-ipad-application

Answer (score 7):

```
[_lblFullName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:20]];
[_lblTicket setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-900" size:12]];
```

You can access the names of your custom fonts in the "Museo Sans" family by running:

```
 NSArray *fonts = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Museo Sans"];

for (NSString *fname in fonts) {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fname size:12.0];
    NSLog(@"name: %@ font: %@", fname, font);
}
```

Whichever string is logged as the name works when used with fontWithName.

Answer (score -1):

In `Swift 2.2`, you may want to do like this:

```
let fonts = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName("Museo Sans")
for name in fonts {
    let font = UIFont(name: name, size: 12)
    print("name: \(font?.fontName) font: \(font)")
}
```